# Unable to pick up all the records from csv, Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-5.0, jmeter-3.2

I am unable to pick up some rows from csv i.e alternate rows are not inserted by jmeter.

for eg: my csv as following data
1)row1data
2)row2data
3)row3data
4)row4data
3000)row3000data

When i run the thread group, only data which is picked up is row1data,row3data etc but row2data, row4data data is skipped

i have tried this with different threadgroup, still result is same

csv set config i have used is as follows :

[image]

I have tried sharing mode as current thread, all thread in csv data set config

Answer (score 0):

Any chance you have a comma in your CSV data set config? If yes, JMeter will consider it as the CSV [delimiter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delimiter) hence you will get incomplete data or a "skip"

You can [increase the JMeter logging verbosity](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging) for the CSV Data Set Config by adding the next lines to *log4j2.xml* file (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

```
<Logger name="org.apache.jmeter.config.CSVDataSet" level="debug"/>
<Logger name="org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer" level="debug"/>
```

JMeter restart will be required to pick the changes up, once done you should see what's going on under the hood in [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging)

---

If you just need to read the next line from the file with each virtual users on each iteration you need to change "Sharing Mode" to `All Threads`.

Alternatively (it's much easier but more resource consuming as well) you can go for [__StringFromFile() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__StringFromFile)